# sql complex like expression @user

Tags: sql, mysql, database, expression

im trying to find all the mentions for the matched username (sam) from the database text code with following:

```
$sql = "select * from tweet where feed like '%@sam%'";
```

this will return all the rows which user have been mention at.

but now the problem is, it also returns rows with @sam3, @sam-dadf or anything that is after @sam..

how can i limit this, so only specific username shows from the text and not all the matching sams.. following are the text format in the database, that is inserted in feed row.

```
 1. i been out with @sam today, but im
    not sure what we should do
 2. we head great party today and all the frineds were invited, such as @sam, @jon, @dan...
 3. i been out today with @samFan and with @dj. << this row should not get pull from database``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `REGEXP` (or `RLIKE`), but watch out for the common regex mistake of looking for the end of the desired "token" as merely a common, negated character class like `[^A-Za-z0-9]` -- instead use the zero-width, "end of word" match construct `[[:>:]]` (which perl's engine and other inspired regexen know as `\b`).

The negated character class fails to match at the end-of-string:

```
mysql> SELECT 'I am @sam' REGEXP '@sam[^A-Za-z0-9]' AS "Does This Match?";
+------------------+
| Does This Match? |
+------------------+
|                0 | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

where the word boundary match succeeds:

```
mysql> SELECT 'I am @sam' REGEXP '@sam[[:>:]]' AS "Does This Match?";
+------------------+
| Does This Match? |
+------------------+
|                1 | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If `[[:>:]]` isn't quite right for your application (because your "username" character set is not what the MySQL regex engine thinks of as one side of a word boundary in your locale), you can, alternatively, specify a negated character class and separately test for end-of-string:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (feed REGEXP '@sam[^A-Za-z0-9]' or feed REGEXP '@sam$')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using mysql regular expression to try to achive this.

Search the string sfor your required text, disregarding selected followup chars

[MySQL Regular Expressions](http://www.wellho.net/regex/mysql.html)

Comment: thanks for the link, but need example code that uses @sam example

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with MySql.

In Microsoft SQL Server, the Like clause can allow you to specify fields to NOT match.

Ex:
if ('I like @Spam.' LIKE '%@Spam[^a-z]%') SELECT 1

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where feed REGEXP '@sam[^A-Za-z0-9]'